# How to find all symbolic links pointing to a particular folder?

Tags: linux, unix

In my Linux server, there are some symbolic links look like:

```
quick_job -> /home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/quick_job/
```

Now if I want to find out all the symbolic links to `/home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/quick_job/`, according to this "[symbolic link: find all files that link to this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184849/symbolic-link-find-all-files-that-link-to-this-file)", I tried this command:

```
find -L / -samefile /home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/quick_job/
```

but in ssh it shows:

```
find: /: Permission denied
```

So, what is going wrong here? And, what is the right command to run to find all symbolic links pointing to folder `/home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/quick_job/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` tells you that you have no access to `/` directory.

To search in a directory you have access to:

```
find -L /home/thejobco -samefile /home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/quick_job/
```

Comment: [thejobco@needsmet ~]$ find /home/thejobco -L -samefile /home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/quick_job/.
find: invalid predicate `-L'