# Get ONLY sym links to a file

Tags: linux, find, symlink

I looked into [symbolic link: find all files that link to this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184849/symbolic-link-find-all-files-that-link-to-this-file) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184849/symbolic-link-find-all-files-that-link-to-this-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532241/linux-find-all-symlinks-of-a-given-original-file-reverse-readlink) but they didn't seem to solve the problem.

if I do `find -L -samefile path/to/file`
the result contains hard links as well as sym links.

I've been trying to come up with a solution to fetch ONLY sym links, but can't seem to figure it out.
I've been trying to combine `-samefile` and `-type l` but that got me nowhere.

```
man find
```

says you can combine some options into an expression, but I failed to do it properly.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I completely misread the question at first.

To find only symlinks to a certain file, I think it's still good approach to combine multiple commands. 
So you know the file you want to link to, let's call it `targetfile.txt`. We have our directory structure like this:

```
$ ls -laR
.:
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  4 telorb telorb 4096 Mar 28 09:51 .
drwxrwxr-x 57 telorb telorb 4096 Mar 28 09:49 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 telorb telorb   21 Mar 28 09:51 another_file.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 telorb telorb 4096 Mar 28 09:52 folder1
drwxrwxr-x  2 telorb telorb 4096 Mar 28 09:53 folder2
-rw-rw-r--  3 telorb telorb   28 Mar 28 09:52 targetfile.txt

./folder1:
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 telorb telorb 4096 Mar 28 09:52 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 telorb telorb 4096 Mar 28 09:51 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 3 telorb telorb   28 Mar 28 09:52 hardlink
lrwxrwxrwx 1 telorb telorb   17 Mar 28 09:49 symlink1 -> ../targetfile.txt

./folder2:
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 telorb telorb 4096 Mar 28 09:57 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 telorb telorb 4096 Mar 28 09:51 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 3 telorb telorb   28 Mar 28 09:52 hardlink2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 telorb telorb   17 Mar 28 09:57 symlink2_to_targetfile -> ../targetfile.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 telorb telorb   19 Mar 28 09:53 symlink_to_anotherfile -> ../another_file.txt
```

The file in `folder1/hardlink` is a hardlink to targetfile.txt, `folder1/symlink1` is a symbolic link we are interested, and same with `folder2/symlink2_to_targetfile`. There is also another symlink to another file, which we are not interested in.

The approach I would take is first use `find . -type l` to get symbolic links recursively from specified folder (and we still have full path information).

Then pipe that to `xargs` and `ls -l` to get the information which file the link is pointing to, and finally grep our `targetfile.txt`, so that we remove links that are not pointing to our desired file. The command in full:

```
find . -type l | xargs -I % ls -l % | grep targetfile.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 telorb telorb 17 Mar 28 09:57 ./folder2/symlink2_to_targetfile -> ../targetfile.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 telorb telorb 17 Mar 28 09:49 ./folder1/symlink1 -> ../targetfile.txt
```

The `xargs -I % ls -l %` sometimes confuses people. Basically with `-I %` you are telling xargs that `%` sign will denote all places where you want xargs place the input it receives. So it will effectively replace it to `ls -l output_of_find_command`

Comment: thank you very much, that worked great! :)
If I run the command from / directory, it takes extremely long time to produce results (over 10 minutes). But when I call the command from my ~ dir, it just flies and gives me the correct answer. A friend of mine came up with a different solution; I'll post it here in case someone finds it helpful.
" find $(find -L -samefile path/to/file 2>/dev/null) -type l"
A good thing to add 2>dev/null to avoid splashing the screen with error messages when trying to access some files with insufficient permissions. I will accept your answer :)

Comment: It's a good idea to add that error redirection to null indeed. I think your friends 2 find commands  is not bad solution either.