# how to find symbolic links of an icon that points to another symbolic link

Tags: bash

In the sardi icon theme I have noticed that there are symbolic links to symbolic links to symbolic links to the original image.

The command

```
ls -lR . | grep ^l | wc
```

shows me i have 3511 symbolic links times 5 icons sets. 
15,000 links to check.

Is there a (bash) way to show me all the links that point to another symbolic link?

Comment: Links, both hard and symbolic, is one way only. If you want to see all links "pointing" to another link, you have to check *all* the links in your entire system and see which ones point to the specified target. Basically you need to do `find / -type l` and check each file (which will indeed be several thousands) if they point to the target.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184849/symbolic-link-find-all-files-that-link-to-this-file

Comment: @LeoIzen I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `find` and some bash features:

```
shopt -s extglob
find . -type l | while read -r; do
    t="$(readlink "$REPLY")"
    if [[ "$t" != /* ]]; then
        t="${REPLY%%*([^/])}$t"
    fi
    [ -L "$t" ] && echo "$REPLY"
done
```

Or all in one line:

```
find . -type l | while read -r; do t="$(readlink "$REPLY")"; if [[ "$t" != /* ]]; then t="${REPLY%%*([^/])}$t"; fi; [ -L "$t" ] && echo "$REPLY"; done
```

- `find . -type l` finds all symlinks.
- Then for each symlink `$REPLY`, we get its target `$t` using `readlink`.
- If the target is not an absolute name (doesn't start with `/`), we prepend the dirname from the original path `$REPLY` (the expression `${REPLY%%*([^/])}` removes all trailing non-slash characters).
- If the target is also a symlink (`-L`), we output the original name `$REPLY`.

The `extglob` extension must be enabled to get `*([^/])` to work.