# PHP Get all Symlink files?

Tags: php, symlink

Is there any way to get all symlinks for specific file?

So let say, I have a file here: `home/test/a.png`

and I have created 2 symlinks for this file:

```
home/test-a.png
home/testb/a.png
```

In this circumstances, is there any function to get those 2 symlinks back?

Something like

```
get_all_symlinks('home/test/a.png')
```

which will pass following:

```
array(
'home/test-a.png',
'home/testb/a.png'
)
```

Or at least, 
is there any function or way to get to know 
if this file has symlink(s) to it?

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4532279/5440709

Comment: Try `readlink()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.readlink.php `var_dump(readlink('home/test/a.png'));`

Comment: @Twisty no, `readlink` is for symlink. `home/test/a.png` is not a symlink, but actual file. `readlink — Returns the target of a symbolic link`

Comment: @RayC maybe I misread your question. You did ask *Is there any way to get all symlinks for specific file?*

Comment: @Twisty Correct. I just meant it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `scandir` with `is_link` and then `readlink` to create the array. Here are the docs for these functions,
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Comment: It's tricky because symlinks are interpreted as relative pathnames, so you need to determine if the resolved pathname points to the original path.