# file all files that link to any file in a specific directory

Tags: bash, shell, find, posix, symlink

I need to do this on a mac/linux:

- Given: some directory such as /usr/local/lib/node_modules
- Find: all links that are symbolic links to any files within the given directory

I would like to remove those links since the directory does not exist anymore and provide a cleaner working environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the answer to this question:

[Linux: Find all symlinks of a given 'original' file? (reverse 'readlink')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532241/linux-find-all-symlinks-of-a-given-original-file-reverse-readlink)

The basic idea is that you are doing an `ls -al` on every directory and grepping the contents to see if it contains the directory as a target of the link (instead of file as in previous answer). Just replace `/usr/share/applications` with your directory, and the `.*` matches all files or subfolders. The `\->` ensures it matches link targets instead of normal filenames.

Example:

`pax$ find / -exec ls -ald {} ';' 2>/dev/null | grep '\-> /usr/share/applications.*'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pax pax 23 2010-06-12 14:56 /home/pax/applications_usr_share
                                         -> /usr/share/applications`